# android apk file installation

Tags: android

I am trying to install apk file in G1 device and get following error:

Failure[INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

I have already change the name of main file using Manifest too. change the icon too.

though the same problem is come over.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in Advance..
Sunil Mishra

Answer (score 13):

Do you have some valuable application data, that prevents you from uninstalling the app, and then installing the new version?

Try the ADB command for reinstalling already existing application:

```
adb install -r <path to your .apk>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to change the name of the package, which is a lot of work with no benefit. What you should do is uninstall it. Ether choose Settings->Applications->Manage Applications and remove it from there or issue the command:

```
adb uninstall com.package.name
```

Answer (score 1):

The android Manifest file has version numbers and works based on the package name not the dispayed name so I think if you update your verion numbers in the manifest, repackage and deploy then you should be able to install as an upgrade which will preserve your user data.  I've done it 45 times for my app in the process of debugging.

regards,

Fin